# link_to remote: true redirecting to HTML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, respond-to

At the `/tags` page I have a link with `remote: true`. It should be a link to an ajax request. But there are two requests, as JS and as HTML.

`<%= link_to 'New', new_tag_path, class: "btn btn-outline btn-primary", remote: true %>`

```
INFO -- : Started GET "/tags/new" for 192.168.18.236 at 2018-06-13 11:44:18 -0300
INFO -- : Processing by TagsController#new as JS
INFO -- :   Rendered tags/_form.html.erb (41.0ms)
INFO -- :   Rendered tags/_modal.html.erb (41.5ms)
INFO -- :   Rendered tags/new.js.erb (49.2ms)
INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 63ms (Views: 50.3ms | ActiveRecord: 2.2ms)
INFO -- : Started GET "/tags/new" for 192.168.18.236 at 2018-06-13 11:44:18 -0300
INFO -- : Processing by TagsController#new as HTML
INFO -- : Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 1.9ms)
FATAL -- : 
ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template tags/new, application/new with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:
```

If I provide a `new.html.erb`, this MissingTemplate error is over, but the page is redirected to new.html.
What could be wrong with that request or that link?

**Edit** The controller code
    class TagsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_tag, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :fix_correct_name]
      before_action :set_tags, only: [:new, :edit]

```
  # GET /tags/new
  def new
    @tag = Tag.new
  end

  # GET /tags/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tags
  def create
    @tag = Tag.new(tag_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @tag.save
        format.html { redirect_to action: "index", notice: 'Tag adicionada.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_tag
      @tag = Tag.find(params[:id])
    end

    def set_tags
      @tags = Tag.all.pluck(:name, :id)
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def tag_params
      params.fetch(:tag, {}).permit(:name, :parent_id, :tag_name, :parent_name, :no_parent)
    end
end
```

Comment: show your controller code that serves the ajax request

Answer (score 0):

In your new action, you’ll need a `response_to` to handle the ajax call

```
def new
  @tag = Tag.new
  respond_to { |format| format.js }
end
```

Also, you’ll need a `new.js.erb` file and a `_new.html.erb` partial to handle the response and update the view.

Inside your new.js.erb, you will have to render the view with something like this

```
$(“div-id-name”).html(“<%= j render partial: “new” %>”)
```

And your new partial will simply hold your form (or whatever is it you wanna render)

Comment: I put `respond_to { |format| format.js }` without success. I realized  new.js is getting rendered, but `data-remote="true"` is not preventing redirect to new.html

Comment: I made it work now, only adding  `require rails-ujs` to application.js and adding rails-ujs gem. But I don`t know why.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work now, only replacing `require jquery_ujs` by `require rails-ujs` to `application.js` and adding rails-ujs gem.